# Software for warping video timeline

Tags: video, warp

Is there a software (preferably command-line) that allows warping video timeline?

E.g. I have a 60-seconds source.mkv. Also I have a text file containing list of corresponding points, where every pair is a source and destination point:

```
00:05 --> 00:07
00:07 --> 00:08
00:10 --> 00:10
...
00:40 --> 00:50
01:00 --> 01:00
```

So part [00:00-00:05] will be stretched and become [00:00-00:07] in destination.mkv; [00:05-00:07] will become [00:07-00:08] etc.

I know there's such software for audio (Rubber Band), and for video?

Comment: What's wrong with results when you try to search on Google? For command line, check if FFmpeg does time stretching the way you want, You might have to break the video into small pieces (for different stretch times).

Comment: The wrong is I already did that. That method is inaccurate and can create a video that is longer or shorter than needed.